# Authentication & Authorization Role issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

i'm having a controller name UserController in Admin Area (section). In which i can assign them Roles Admin (A) to User (U) or User (U) to Admin (A).

[image: this is the image of List of All users which i can assign them Roles]

when I change role of any user it updated successfully in database also ,but when I login from application that user of which i had changed the role so user contains its old role.I have put the break point also the variable 'role' is returning the previous Role. i'm surprised that how can 'role' variable return its old role.

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
        string[] role = { obj.GetAll().Where(x => x.EmailAddress ==    username).FirstOrDefault().Role };
        return role;
    }
```

User Controller AssignRole Action in this code i'm updating the Role

```
 public ActionResult AssignRole(int id, string role)
    {
        try
        {
        BOL.tbl_Login user = (BOL.tbl_Login)obj.login.GetById(id);
        if (role == "A")
        {
            user.Role = "U";
        }
        else if (role == "U")
        {
            user.Role = "A";
        }
        else
        {
            user.Role = "U";
        }
        obj.login.Update(user);
        TempData["Msg"] = "Operation Successfully!";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Msg"] = "Error " + ex.Message;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("_Index");
    }
```

and i'm also using

```
   [Authorize(Roles = "A")]
```

I think Entity Framework not returning the newest data.

here is the Data access layer code

```
public override void Update(T data)
    {
        obj.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
        obj.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        Save();

        obj.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that role is saving both previous and current values. AsNoTracking function do not save previous values it only shows current value. Put my code there where you are getting roles or above your method 'getroles' so your problem will be solved

```
    public override IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {

        return obj.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }
```